# Mongoose: How to populate sub properties from within a schema's virtual properties

Tags: mongodb, mongoose, mongoose-schema, mongoose-populate

I have a mongodb schema defined using mongoose and I have some sub documents nested over multiple levels. I want to be able to access these (populated) subdocuments within another schema's virtual properties but I can't seem to do so. I seem to be able to access the documents at the first level of nesting but not further down.

Here's an example of my schemas:

```
const SchemaA = {
   name: {type: string}
   items: [
     {
      schemaB: {
       type: schema.type.ObjectId,
       ref: "B"
      }
     }
   ]
}
```

```
const SchemaB = {
   name: {type: string}
   schemaC: {
       type: schema.type.ObjectId,
       ref: "C"
      }
}
```

```
const SchemaC = {
   types: [{label: {type: String}}]
}
```

What I want to be able to do is access the SchemaC.types from inside a virtual property on SchemaA.

Here's what I want to achieve:

```
SchemaA.virtual("types").get(function(){
   return this.items.map(item => {
       return {name: item.schemaB.name, types: item.schemaB.SchemaC.types}
   })
})
```

From the above `item.schemaB` seems to populate just fine but `item.schemaB.SchemaC` seems to just be the objectId of schemaC.

I'm not sure if this is even possible, to be honest, but I can't seem to find a definitive answer anywhere online so I'm hoping someone on here can help. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So in mongoose you need to use the `populate` method.

```
 .populate({
    path: 'schemaB',
    populate: {
      path: 'schemaC'
    }
  });
```

[mongoose populate](https://mongoosejs.com/docs/populate.html#populate_multiple_documents)